# IDA Free Debugger slows down app substantially

Tags: ida, debugging

I'm using IDA Free to decompile and debug an exectuable (a game, actually).

When starting the debugger, the game runs really, really slow occasionally.

Before, I have used Cheat Engine to debug the game and I did not notice any slowness. The game ran full speed.

Do you have any idea why IDA Free causes the app to slow down? And is there a way to improve debugger performance?